# Problem with stored procedure with parameters and stored procedure with no parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have stored procedures in vb.net app. Once I call the stored procedure with parameters, the other stored procedure with no parameters throw exceptions "Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied."

Comment: That mean you are calling wrong stored procedure.

Comment: There are three votes to close your question so far, all because you have asked a about a problem in your code without showing us the code.  ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information and the code in question is ALWAYS relevant.  Please spend some time reading in the Help Center to learn what constitutes a proper question on this site.

Comment: Can't really understand the question. Can you provide some code perhaps? See [ask].

Comment: No. I am calling correct procedure. It seems that the last called stored procedure held the supplied arguments and resupply to the next stored procedure.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that you are not keeping your database objects local. Are they enclosed in `Using...End Using` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Check your function if it's calling the right name of the stored procedure and has correct parameter/s

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it. It have to clear the stored procedure's sqlcommand

sqlcommand.Parameters.Clear()

before execute the another stored procedure without parameters.